# How this wordpress filter hook works

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I expected: `Default Values MyValue NEW22! Default Values MyValue NEW!`
But am getting: `Default Values MyValue NEW22! NEW!`

Can anyone tell me why?

Code:

```
// First call this
function example_callback2( $string2 ) {
    $new_value2 = $string2 . " NEW22!";
    return $new_value2;
}
add_filter( 'example_filtersubroto', 'example_callback2', 9 );

$value = "Default Values MyValue";
echo $value = apply_filters( 'example_filtersubroto', $value );

// Expected output: Default Values MyValue NEW22! Default Values MyValue NEW!
// Real output: Default Values MyValue NEW22! NEW!
?>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do want like this?

```
        // First call this
        function example_callback2( $string2 ) {
            $new_value2 = $string2 . " NEW22!";
            $new_value2 .= $new_value2;
            return $new_value2;
        }
        add_filter( 'example_filtersubroto', 'example_callback2', 9 );

        $value = "Default Values MyValue";
        echo $value = apply_filters( 'example_filtersubroto', $value );
```

Comment: Thanks you very much sir for you answer. I am not looking output. I want to know how add_filter works here. I use add_filter two times but output should be
"Default Values MyValue NEW22! Default Values MyValue NEW!"

https://gist.github.com/subrotoice/727876770536dc7e31bd54473b196c4b